# How can I get the idle time via dbus while running from /etc/rc.local?

Tags: bash, dbus, ubuntu-21.04

I have a rudimentary bash script that checks if the system has been idle for more than an hour, and if so, shuts it down:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
get_idle_time=`dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime`
idle_time=$(echo $get_idle_time | awk '{print $NF}')
if [[ $idle_time -ge 3600000 ]]; then
shutdown
fi
done
```

I added this script to `/etc/rc.local` so it would always be active:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

bash /home/paulky/shutdown.sh

exit 0
```

Although `bash /home/paulky/shutdown.sh` from a terminal works while I'm logged in, doing it from `/etc/rc.local` seems to prevents Ubuntu from getting to the login screen, and <kbd>F2</kbd> shows this error message repeating itself infinitely:

`Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11.`

I've tried prepending `export DISPLAY=:0` to the start of the script, to no avail.

Comment: `bash /home/paulky/shutdown.sh &`?

Comment: @Cyrus `bash home/paulky/shutdown.sh` is all I needed to do to run the script from a terminal successfully, so I was under the impression it would also be enough for `rc.local`?